# Dividing Polynomial Fitted Curves in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have two 5th order polynomial fits, one of which I have taken the derivative of. I want to divide to the two polynomials and plot the results. From what I can the only way to do this is to use the "deconv" function, but how do I plot the results? Or is there an easier way to do this?

```
cdpdz=coeffvalues(fitresult{2});
%where pn are the coefficients of the first derivative of the fitted polynomial
pp=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6]; 

[divpp.r]=deconv(pp/cdpdz);
```

Comment: So know I want to integrate the function. I would use the polyint function correct?                                                                                                                             intpp=polyint(ptint);                                                But when I use this I get the following errors:  Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in polyint (line 16)
pi = [p./(length(p):-1:1) k];

Error in ptintegrate97 (line 61)
intpt=polyint(ptint);                                                The matrix dimensions do agree. Sorry I'm very new to MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to plot the results, I am assuming that you actually want to calculate the values of the polynomials at many points, and then divide those values.  That is different than the polynomial division that is performed by deconv.

I would suggest that you must make a range of values `x` over which to evaluate the polynomials.  Then use `polyval` to get the values over that range, and divide the two arrays (being careful of zeros in the denominator!)

```
ppval = polyval(pp,x);
cdpdzval = polyval(cdpdz,x);

plot(x,ppval./cdpdzval);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my previous question. So if I now want to integrate the above function, I would use the polyint function right? When I use the polyint function, I get the following errors:                                                                  Error using  ./ 
     Matrix dimensions must agree.

     Error in polyint (line 16)
     pi = [p./(length(p):-1:1) k];

     Error in ptintegrate97 (line 85)
     intpt=polyint(ptint);

Comment: I'm not sure what you are putting as the input to polyint.  You may want to ask a new question.